# Which NSTextView is the First Responder?

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield, first-responder

I'm working on a Cocoa programming exercise, and I need to be able to determine which of two NSTextView objects is currently being edited. I think it's something to do with finding the first responder and checking to see if it's equal to one text field or another, but I can't quite get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to read the [Cocoa Event-Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html), and especially the section called [Responder-Related Tasks](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventHandlingBasics/EventHandlingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH5-SW22). You will find all the information you need.

Comment: Both links are now dead.

Comment: Pretty sure the answer ended up being about looking at the sender in a delegate callback.